# Make module with Python's Nose setUp/tearDown methods

Tags: python, module, functional-testing, nose

I started using python's Nose to execute my functional tests.

I use it with SauceLab's service. I execute the tests from the command line and see the reports on Sauce dashboard.

Now, every test is a class containing setUp() , the_test() , and tearDown() methods.
Inside the setUp() method there are the capabilities passed to Sauce configuring the Browser/version/OS the test will run on.

```
def setUp(self):
        #REMOTE
        desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        desired_capabilities['version'] = '21'
        desired_capabilities['platform'] = 'Windows XP'
        desired_capabilities['name'] = className.getName(self) 
        desired_capabilities['record-video'] = False

        self.wd = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,command_executor="http://the_username:the_API_key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub")
        self.wd.implicitly_wait(10)
```

I would like to do the following...:
Create a separate file containing the setUp and tearDown functions and just call them by name every time exactly where i need them(before and after the test/tests).
Now they exist inside each and every python file I have and they are the same piece of code.

Additionally I think there is a way that nose provides to automatically see the two functions and call them when is needed. Is it feasible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a super class.

```
def MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # do setup stuff
```

Then each of your tests can inherit from MyTestCase. You can then further over ride setUp or tearDown in each test class. But do remember to call the super classes init method as well.

Comment: Why subclass them in `unittest.TestCase`? nose contains the same assert functionality in its own libraries and is pep8 compliant

Comment: He can subclass whatever class he likes really... I'm not being prescriptive. Just telling him that thte solution to not having an identical setUp method on each test class is to use inheritance.